# How to import an mp3 song into iTunes using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, scripting-bridge

I am building a Mac OS Application which needs to import an mp3 file into iTunes...

Can't seem to find any framework that would help me achieve this. The only way I can think of doing this is modifying the "iTunes Music Library.xml".

I'm hoping one of you can point me to a better and cleaner solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Feeling a bit too lazy to type out a complete answer, but take a look at [Scripting Bridge](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH4-SW1), which lets you talk to AppleScriptable apps using Objective-C. It's pretty slick. One of the pieces of sample code in those docs is to talk to iTunes.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I'll take a look at it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so after some research on Scripting Bridge, just like Andrew Madsen suggested. Here is the answer to my own question.

This has been implemented and tested...

1. Add the **ScriptingBridge Framework** to your Mac OS Project.
2. Generate the **iTunes.h** file by writing the following in the terminal.

   `sdef /Applications/iTunes.app | sdp -fh --basename iTunes`
3. Import the newly created **iTunes.h** file into your Mac OS Project and do an **#import "iTunes.h"** in the class you would like to use the Scripting Bridge in.
4. Use this code to add a song to iTunes:

   `iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
   iTunesTrack * track = [iTunes add:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]] to:playlist];`
5. That is all to it.