# How to upload or push songs from my app to iPhone music library in Swift 5

Tags: swift, iphone, mpmediaitem, apple-music, mpmedialibrary

I am building an iOS app in Swift 5 and I am trying to add a song to the user's Apple Music Library, I fetched all the albums, playlists songs using MPMediaLibrary but can't upload it! Is it possible to upload a song to the user's Apple Music Library?

Answer (score 0):

The modification could not be made to the user's music library which could not be done by an app because it's the user decision to decide what songs to be in his/her library. There is no such api to achieve this. This is something like you want to install an app in the user's iPhone without user's intervention, which could not be done.

There is already a similar question with Swift 4.
[Swift 4 Upload song to Apple Music Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332598/swift-4-upload-song-to-apple-music-library)

Edit:

Refer this documentation in case if you want to modify playlist/apply ratings to user's library (with the user authorization)

- [addItem Instance method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmedialibrary/1621278-additem)
- [api documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625)